# how to get posts from my newsfeed on facebook containg certain text using restfb

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb, android-facebook

Hi my task is very straight fw:
I want to query my newsfeed for all the posts it contains(from the last 24 hrs), that has the word **"nice"** in them.
I am using restFB client.
I tried this: (using Graph API)

```
Connection<Post> targetedSearch = facebookClient.fetchConnection(
        "me/home?q=facebook", Post.class, Parameter.with("q", "nice"),
        Parameter.with("type", "post"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best Answer I could find is from [here](http://steve.veerman.ca/2012/facebook-api-fql-tutorial/), is using FQL

```
SELECT post_id, app_id, source_id, updated_time, filter_key, attribution, message, action_links, likes, permalink FROM stream WHERE filter_key ="nf" and strpos(lower(message),lower("nice")) > 0
```